# Cannot connect to SMTP server

Tags: smtp, centos, postfix-mta

Hello I have problems sending emails from my Outlook using my server SMTP how ever if I send the emails from php all whent OK. From Outlook I get this message...

421 Cannot connect to SMTP server 74.208.230.18

But server IP and port 25 are open

Any ideas ??
    [root@mipagina ~]# postfix status
    postfix/postfix-script: the Postfix mail system is running: PID: 15758

```
[root@mipagina ~]# netstat -tulpn|grep 25
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:25                  0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      15758/master
tcp        0      0 :::25                       :::*                        LISTEN      15758/master
```

Comment: Most ISPs block outgoing port 25. Make sure thats not the case.

Answer (score 0):

Most ISPs block port 25. Better switch to port 587.